# DRIconf in Ubuntu 64x plus ATI GPU or something more?

Tags: wine, games

I've been trying to get Call of Duty 2 to work in Wine in Ubuntu. It gives me a black screen. So I tried the fix suggested by the wine apphq and downloaded DRIconf. Funny thing is that it can't find my direct rendering device.

"Could not detect any configurable direct-rendering capable devices. DRIconf will be started in expert mode"

When I enter into it in Expert Mode is just errors out anyway.

`fglrxinfo` gives me:

```
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4200 Series
OpenGL version string: 3.3.11627 Compatibility Profile Context
```

That shows me my driver is installed correctl,y right?  World of Goo which is Linux native and requires direct rendering works like a charm.

So I'm wondering, is there some other workaround? Is there a bigger issue? Does me running 64-bit affect it at all?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, running 64 bit should not affect it. I run 32bit applications on Wine just fine.

Secondly, I would not suggest using DRIconf with Fglrx, the proprietary AMD/ATI driver, because DRIconf is for Open Source drivers. My suggestion would be to try PlayOnLinux and see if that has an entry for Call Of Duty.

If it does, use that to install the game and it will set it up *just right*, avoiding any issues with current versions of Wine.

If the issue still persists, your best option is to file a bug on Wine's bug tracker.

---

### To Install PlayOnLinux:

Use the command appropriate for your version of Ubuntu (I've included the command for 12.04). See here for the complete list: http://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_precise.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```